# FedEx Login fails with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently working on automating the login process for FedEx using Selenium. The automation process runs smoothly up to the point where the bot clicks the login button. However, after clicking, it prints an error message stating, 'We are having trouble establishing a connection. Please refresh the page.' How can I address this issue and ensure a successful login automation? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
[image: this is what i get when login is clicked]

I used selenium to open the fedex login site and enter the login credentials and press the login button. It does that but login fails with the following message:
"We are having trouble establishing a connection. Please refresh the page."
I was expecting a successful login for correct credential and "incorrect login id/password" for wrong credentials.

Comment: its probably bot detection. try using ```undetected-chrome-driver ```

Comment: You should use their API: https://developer.fedex.com/api/en-us/home.html

Comment: @RolandasUlevicius it worked thank you